# Generic route for current user in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm building an API in .NET Core 1.1. I have a lot of routes, for example `/api/users/:id/posts` to get the posts of the user with the specified ID. Other sites I've found (notably [Discord](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user)) accept a generic parameter such as `@me` to reference the current user instead of specifying the ID. How can I implement this in .NET Core?

I take a JWT in the `Authorization` header and I have a custom `User` object that is filled with its information using a custom middleware, including the user ID. I therefore have the ID ready by the time any route or controller is used, but I don't know how I can specify a generic route that will automatically use that ID when called with `@me` or something similar. How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT:** When I get some time I'm going to write middleware to implement this. I'm leaving the question open so that I can post the solution when I'm able to write it.

Comment: you could write some middleware to parse the route before its processed by the routing engine